# GCC 5 error, maybe used uninitialized

Tags: gcc, gcc-warning

How do I initialize ua in this struct?

```
static int clk_init_vdd_class(struct device *dev, struct clk *clk, int num,
             unsigned long *fmax, int *uv, int *ua)
```

[Here is is rest of code, krait-8974.c](https://github.com/Jcfunk/navelA-990/blob/master/arch/arm/mach-msm/clock-krait-8974.c)

Comment: The code in your question isn't enough to let us answer. The linked code is 901 lines. Show us a smaller sample *in the question* that actually shows the problem.

Comment: Sorry, very new at c.  Trying to compile with lestest GCC, code didn't have error in previous versions.

Comment: @Jcfunk: Older gcc could probably detect the problem, but maybe that warning wasn't enabled by default?  It's generally a good idea to write code that compiles without errors with `-Wall`.

Comment: The warning comes because there are possible code paths where those variables are accessed uninitialized.  The `parse_tbl` function sometimes returns before setting those values, depending on the result of functions whose source code is not visible to the compiler.   To make your code robust, the best solution would be to modify `parse_tbl` to make sure it never returns a non-negative value without setting those variables.

Comment: Also, this code is illegal if `int` is not 32-bit (some compilers use 64-bit int) so it would be good to check that.

Comment: @Matt McNabb Thanks, I'll look into all of it.

Comment: @Peter Cordes -Wall is set, I think it has to do with newer c standard. C89 allowed uninitialized variables.  Plus optimization levels did -O2 now trying -O3

Comment: @Jcfunk: I'm pretty sure gcc has had warnings for using uninitialized data for years, even with the default `-std=gnu90`.  I guess in this case it just wasn't sure this could happen until newer gcc came along with a better optimizer.  (`-Wuninitialized` doesn't warn unless it can prove that there's a code path that will use it uninitialized.  `-Wmaybe-uninitialized` is enabled by `-Wall`, though, and it should have caught the possibility.  hrm, I'm not sure what's up.)  See the gcc manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer, 
Line # 683
Edited by adding

```
int *uv = 0, *ua = 0;
```

Here is full code

```
    static int
clock_krait_8974_driver_probe(struct platform_device *pdev)
    {
    struct device *dev = &pdev->dev;
    struct clk *c;
    int speed, pvs, pvs_ver, config_ver, rows, cpu;
    unsigned long *freq, cur_rate, aux_rate;
    int *uv = 0, *ua = 0;
    u32 *dscr = NULL, vco_mask, config_val;
    int ret;

    vdd_l2.regulator[0] = devm_regulator_get(dev, "l2-dig");
    if (IS_ERR(vdd_l2.regulator[0])) {
        dev_err(dev, "Unable to get l2-dig regulator!\n");
        return PTR_ERR(vdd_l2.regulator[0]);
    }
```